# is NSUserDefaults store values perminetly

Tags: ios4

I wrote some code for NSUserdefaults and I sent the values. I released the app. Again I to want relase the app with new version (1.1). Will NsUserDefaults keep the values set in version 1.0 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using the NSUserDefaults](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208485/using-the-nsuserdefaults)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES, it will. NSUserDefaults will be kept on upgrade. They are delete if you uninstall the app from the device.

Comment: @pratapshaik:You're welcome. If the answer is ok for you, don't forget to accept it or upvote it :-)