# Does NSUserDefaults get erased when an app gets updated?

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults

In my App i am using NSUserDefaults to save some data. I have a doubt regarding this when i update the app in App Store, Will The Data in NSUserDefaults will remain same or it is removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it will not be erased on updating

Answer (score 15):

NSUserDefaults will not be erased during update, but it will be removed when you uninstall an app.

Comment: Is the data lost in nsuserdefaluts when we double click the home button and remove the object.

Comment: @Raptor - Wait what? that is NOT uninstall...NSuserDefaults won't be deleted when you force the app to quit - your second comment is wrong